# horizontal alignment with bootstrap.css (or regular css override)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out Twitter's  bootstrap.css, want to get the `<h2>` and the image to align horizontally, right now they're on top of each other. Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/P335E/2/

what's the simplest way with bootstrap.css to achieve this?

```
<div class="span8">

<h2>Kutcher</h2>
<ul class="media-grid">
 <li>
 <a>
 <img alt="mashable" class="thumbnail" src= "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=aplusk">
</a>
</li>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `media-grid`, you can just hack on the CSS a little to produce this result: http://jsfiddle.net/P335E/3/

However, I would recommend against using `media-grid` if your use case is a single image and user name. Instead, you should really use some custom HTML and CSS. For example, an `a.user` with floated `img` and `h2` sub-elements would work fine.

You can see the latter approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/P335E/4/

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to aligh right:

```
<div class="pull-right">Text at right side</div>
```